# sysdate -1 issue

Tags: sql, oracle

so im running this query the bit where * next to it is where im stuck i want my search to bring up data only with yesterdays date but my query is bringing back no results even though i know there is data from yesterday, i cant use dates as i want my script to run automatically everyday

06-JUL-18 09.49.53.000000000 - this is what the date shows as orginally on the table and below is the desc of the table, the reason i have put substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18), is because i only want to see some of the date and time

CREATION_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)

```
Select substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18),
       A.Message_Class,
       A.Channel,
       A.Data_Centre,
       B.Line_Of_Business,
       count(*) 
From   Payld_Data.Received_Messages A,
       Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
Where  A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id
and    a.message_class = 'IR-CIS-VERIFY-RESP'
**and Creation_Timestamp like sysdate -1**
group by substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18),
       A.Message_Class,
       A.Channel,
       A.Data_Centre,
       B.Line_Of_Business;
```

Comment: I suppose the column `Creation_Timestamp` is a `VARCHAR2`. How are the dates saved?

Comment: like this to start of metadata 





11-JUL-18 13.28.13

Comment: The point here is what is the type of the column Creation_Timestamp. Please try DESC of your table and post the type of that column

Comment: 06-JUL-18 09.49.53.000000000

CREATION_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: No single full stops/periods FTW! At least a few commas

Comment: just a note, sysdate NOW in the form of a DATE. systimestamp is NOW in the form of a timestamp - just in case you ever need this

Comment: don't do like a DATE minus one, nothing will come back from that if you've got a timestamp...define the window of time you want included and use a > and < predicate...test it with a SELECT on just that data and then add it to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore my previous answer since your column is not a string.
Try the following:

```
....
AND Creation_Timestamp >= TRUNC(sysdate-1)
AND Creation_Timestamp < TRUNC(sysdate)
....
```

Furthermore, instead of `substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18)`, you should use `TO_CHAR(Creation_Timestamp, 'DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS')` or whatever format you prefer.
Both in the `select` and in the `group by`.

Comment: thank you so much this worked, but as this has come back with thousands of rows because it is showing rows for each timestamp, how do i run it to show 1 row of how many messages were received the day before?

Comment: "Try the following" ... why? You can improve your answer by explaining (1) what is wrong with the OP's code and (2) why this solution will resolve the problem.

Comment: Also, this will return results for midnight of today as well as results for yesterday.

Comment: @RobertKock all of these 3 scrips u have told me about work and bring back the same results so whats the difference in the way its written?

Comment: Select substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, count(*) 
From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id and a.message_class = 'IR-CIS-VERIFY-RESP'
and Creation_Timestamp between trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate)
group by substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;

Comment: Select TO_CHAR(Creation_Timestamp, 'DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS'), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, count(*) 
From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id and a.message_class = 'IR-CIS-VERIFY-RESP'
and Creation_Timestamp between trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate)
group by TO_CHAR(Creation_Timestamp, 'DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS'), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;

Comment: Select TO_CHAR(Creation_Timestamp, 'DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS'), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, count(*) 
From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id and a.message_class = 'IR-CIS-VERIFY-RESP'
and Creation_Timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1) and creation_timestamp < trunc(sysdate)
group by TO_CHAR(Creation_Timestamp, 'DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS'), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;

Comment: the `substring` instead of `to_char` makes you dependent on a session parameter. Works the same but is ugly. The comparison instead of `between` is just in order to avoid eventual records with a creation exactly on midnight.

Comment: thanks the char bit makes sense, so should i use  between trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate) or and Creation_Timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1) and creation_timestamp < trunc(sysdate) ?

Comment: You should use the latter since the first one returns also eventual records that are created exactly on midnight (not very likely though)

Comment: so use this one yeh? Creation_Timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1) and creation_timestamp < trunc(sysdate)

Answer (score 2):

```
and Creation_Timestamp like sysdate -1
```

is effectively the same as:

```
and Creation_Timestamp = TO_CHAR( sysdate -1, (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' ) )
```

This will likely have a hours, minutes, seconds and fractional seconds component which your `LIKE` condition will try to match. Since there are no values from yesterday at the exact same hours, minutes, seconds and fractional seconds then your query will not return anything.

Instead, you need to query on a range:

```
Select substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18),
       A.Message_Class,
       A.Channel,
       A.Data_Centre,
       B.Line_Of_Business,
       count(*) 
From   Payld_Data.Received_Messages A
       INNER JOIN Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
       ON ( A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id )
Where  a.message_class = 'IR-CIS-VERIFY-RESP'
and    Creation_Timestamp >= TRUNC( sysdate ) - 1
and    Creation_Timestamp  < TRUNC( sysdate )
group by substr(Creation_Timestamp, 1, 18),
       A.Message_Class,
       A.Channel,
       A.Data_Centre,
       B.Line_Of_Business;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same format for both and do a simple string comparison

```
AND TO_CHAR(Creation_Timestamp, ‘YYYYMMDD’) = TO_CHAR(Sysdate - 1, ‘YYYYMMDD’)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue is here:

```
and Creation_Timestamp **like** sysdate -1
```

the **like** operator usually means that'll search for text containing something as in you're trying to find every string that has the word `dog`:

```
where column_name like "%dog%"
```

So you should either go for `=` or `<` or `<=`

**If you want exactly yesterday:**

```
and Creation_Timestamp = sysdate -1
```

**If you want all the days before today**

```
and Creation_Timestamp < sysdate
```

**If you want to do similar as above but stating the `sysdate-1`**

```
and Creation_Timestamp <= sysdate -1
```

**edit:** Something I'll have to add since I'm not sure is how the hours in timestamp would affect this situation. I don't know if will simply work as above or if you'll need cast is as a date as in:

```
and CAST(Creation_Timestamp as date) < SYSDATE
```

Comment: `sysdate -1` is not "exactly yesterday". It is the single point in time 24 hours ago with the same hours, minutes and seconds as of now it will only get a match that has that exact time and no others from yesterday. If you want all the values from yesterday then you either need a range or to truncate the time back to midnight and compare on that.

Comment: Why the downvote (whoever it was)? Anyways, casting the timestamp as date wouldn't get rid of the hours, thus making SYSDATE hourless?

Comment: No, `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types both have hour, minute and second components in Oracle. `TIMESTAMP` has fractional seconds and time zone as well. So changing from an implicit to an explicit `CAST` on `Creation_Timestamp` from a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` will do nothing to help as you will still need the time components to be a match.

Comment: I see, TIL. I guess that when I worked with PLSQL all dates were base 00h00s and that's why I thought I didn't need to TRUNC() it. Thanks for the learning experience! cheers

Answer (score -2):

In case your `Creation_Timestamp` is a **string** with format `DD-Mon-YY`, followed by the time, you should try the following:

```
....
AND Creation_Timestamp LIKE TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'DD-Mon-YY') || '%'
....
```

**UPDATE**
Ignore this answer since the column is not a string.
I don't delete this one since the comments are important

Comment: I agree it loioks like its stored as a string but probably not formatted as yyyy-mm-dd, due to the substr(creation_timestamp,1,18) - as a string the format could entirely be based on external NLS type settings and not even the Oracle ones.

Comment: this came back with no results?

Comment: I just edited the answer since the format you gave reports the month alphanumerically. So try `DD-Mon-YY`

Comment: I'm very curious who downvoted this answer. I know it's not correct. I mentioned that. But I don't wanna delete it because of the important comments.

Comment: Simple, don’t post multiple answers. You should have updated this one instead of creating a new one.